# Difference between import X and import * as X in node.js (ES6 / Babel)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a node.js library `lib` written in ES6 (compiled with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) in which I export the following submodules:

```
"use strict";

import * as _config from './config';
import * as _db from './db';
import * as _storage from './storage';

export var config = _config;
export var db = _db;
export var storage = _storage;
```

If from my main project I include the library like this

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
console.log(lib);
```

I can see the proper output and it work as expected `{ config: ... }`. However, if I try to include the library like this:

```
import lib from 'lib';
console.log(lib);
```

it will be `undefined`.

Can someone explain what is happening here? Aren't the two import methods supposed to be equivalent? If not, what difference am I missing?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
```

is asking for an object with all of the named exports of 'lib'.

---

```
export var config = _config;
export var db = _db;
export var storage = _storage;
```

are named exports, which is why you end up with an object like you did.

---

```
import lib from 'lib';
```

is asking for the `default` export of `lib`.

---

e.g.

```
export default 4;
```

would make `lib === 4`. It does not fetch the named exports. To get an object from the default export, you'd have to explicitly do

```
export default {
  config: _config,
  db: _db,
  storage: _storage
};
```

Answer (score 19):

Just adding to [Logan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387018/3281978) solution because understanding import with brackets, * and without solved a problem for me.

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
```

is the equivalent of:

```
import {config, db, storage} as lib from 'lib';
```

Where the * is similar to a wildcard that imports all of the `export var` from lib.

```
export var config;
export var db;
export var storage;
```

Alternatively, using:

```
import lib from 'lib';
```

Allows you to only access the default export:

```
// lib.js
export default storage;
```

Using {} also only imports specific components from the module, [which reduces the footprint with bundlers like Webpack.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41927090/3281978)

While:

```
import storage, { config, db } from './lib'
```

would import all modules including `export default storage;`

See Dan Abramov's answer:
[When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import/36796281)

Comment: Only that there is no `import {…} as … from …` syntax

Comment: Edited. You're right, there is no spread operator for {...}, I should have used etc instead.

Comment: (Of course there's no spread/rest syntax, as this is not object literal/destructuring). Still there is no `{…} as …` syntax in imports, so "*is the same as*" is meaningless. (I don't think you meant "*produces the same syntax error as*")

Comment: That's correct. Updated the answer for clarity. I used 'is the same as' because smaller words are more accessible. I've changed it to 'equivalent of' to be more specific.

Comment: But can you explain what `import {config, db, storage} as lib from 'lib';` does? It's not described anywhere

Answer (score 5):

`import X from Y;` is a syntax sugar.

`import lib from 'lib';`

is equal to

`import { default as lib } from 'lib';`