# How to use react-test-renderer/shallow with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use `react-test-renderer/shallow` to test my react component.

But when I `import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';`

`tsc` give me an error `'Module '"/Users/dulin/workspace/react-ts-webpack2/node_modules/@types/react-test-renderer/shallow/index"' has no default export.`

So, How to `import` `ShallowRenderer` with `typescript`

-- update --

finally, I change my test filename from `index.test.tsx` -> `index.test.jsx` to avoid the `tsc` error caused by `definition`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import * as ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import PanelHead from '../';

describe('PanelHead test suites', () => {

  it('t-1', () => {

    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    renderer.render(<PanelHead />)
    const result = renderer.getRenderOutput();

    expect(result.type).toBe('div');

  });

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can only use `import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';` if it is default exported. It looks like it is not default exported so that you can't use the above syntax. You can import it as

```
import * as ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
```

Now, to create a `ShallowRenderer` you can call the method `ShallowRenderer.createRenderer()`

```
const myShallowRenderer = ShallowRenderer.createRenderer();
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386631/difference-between-import-x-and-import-as-x-in-node-js-es6-babel).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: yes,  it works. but there is a new problem, `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

Comment: I guess the `react-test-renderer` lack some definitions. so, to avoid the `tsc` type check, I change my test filename from `*.test.tsx` to `*.test.jsx`

Comment: Looking at the definitions, You need to call the function `createRenderer` to create the get the `ShallowRenderer`.  So you can do `ShalloRenderer.createRenderer()`

Answer (score 0):

Although the docs recommend using `new ShallowRenderer()`, this is in a way taking advantage of the "looseness" of JavaScript. Since the library is not exporting something with a constructor, the TypeScript compiler (rightfully) complains about it. You can use the regular recommended import statement:

```
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
```

and then instead of using the `new` keyword just call the `createRenderer` function to get an instance.

```
const shallowRenderer = ShallowRenderer.createRenderer();
```

Happy coding!