# Strange notice in actions import

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've noticed strange behavior in my react-redux actions import.
So, I import `import * as types from './types';` as usual, everything is clean in my console and all code is works.

But I'm worried about this little error:
[image]

What does it means and why my chrome console think this is kinda an error?
Anything I should be worried about?

Answer (score 0):

how you export your const , component from ./types  file matters in import. 
check below link

[Difference between import X and import * as X in node.js (ES6 / Babel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386631/difference-between-import-x-and-import-as-x-in-node-js-es6-babel)

Comment: I know difference between exports.
My question about syntax error in google chrome console. Your answer is not relevant to my question.