# i got a error about render Link component of react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

In my simple app,one of my component need the Link component of react-router,like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><Link to="/">javascript</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/">python</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/">java</Link></li>
</ul>
```

when i import Link in this way:

```
import { BrowserRouter as  Link} from 'react-router-dom'
```

i got a error:

```
React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child
```

and if i import Link like this :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
```

or this

```
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom'
```

that will get nothing errors,anyone can tell me what different in above three ways of import Link component.
my react-router-dom version is 4.3.1

Comment: In the first one your're not importing Link. You're just importing BrowserRouter and renaming it to Link

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386631/difference-between-import-x-and-import-as-x-in-node-js-es6-babel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to import the **Link** component is:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

The way you do it: `import { BrowserRouter as  Link}` is not the correct way, since you are just importing the **BrowserRouter** component and renaming it to "Link".

Comment: i got your mind ,thx! and one more question,why `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom' `is work?

Comment: @TinLen Because of the `,` between `BrowserRouter as Router` and `Route`. In a sentence that statement imports the `BrowserRouter` named as `Router` and the `Route` and the `Link` which are not renamed. You could also split that into: `import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'`, `import { Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'`.