# Cannot import the body-parser module in typesript

Tags: typescript, body-parser

Error image :

[image]

I don't quite understand the error message:

`Error TS1259 (TS) Module '"D:/CloudStorage/..../node_modules/@types/body-parser/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag`

I don't quite understand how to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it

```js
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser"
```

Comment: im not sure but. because body-parser does not have a ES default export. so we import all of  the exported functions as default. refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31387018/12067977

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing typescript library for body-parser:

```
npm i @types/body-parser
```

Answer (score -1):

fixed it -

`import bodyParser = require('body-parser');`

solved it, any ideas why this worked?

Comment: no. and also this is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Okay .. but it clearly does work so what exactly is happening here?